Understand nominal current of Phoenix Contact PCB headers
The PCB header MSTBVA 2,5 HC/ 2-G-5,08 (1924305) from Phoenix Contact is listed with a nominal current of 16A.
Does this mean that I can load each pin with 16 A simultaneously or only both in total?
I cannot find this information in the datasheet.

Careful, this is the HC variant, the normal one is only 12A. This needs to mate an HC plug for this spec to be valid.

It's per-contact, subject to the derating curves (as mentioned in the first paragraph). There will be some heating between adjacent pins at high current and so there is a particular chart for this on page 6.

Figure 1. Derating for multipole connectors.
As can be seen they all run at 16 A up to 60°C but the 5 and 12-pos connectors are derated after that while the 2-pos connector is good to about 76°C.
The centre-pin of a 5-pos connector only has marginally better heat dissipation than the pins in the centre of the 12-pos connector.
